# Name for the fallacy where a person claims that bias always proves the opposite?

Tags: fallacies

I'm unsure how to word this as usual. An example of what I'm talking about would be:

X claims that the dicerolls in a video game are biased.
Y claims it only appears so because of negativity bias, which is real.
X then takes count of all the die rolls across several matches in the video game, and finds that the results are in fact biased.
Y claims the results must be fraudulent because the claim must be false due to negativity bias.

Essentially, Y is refuting evidence because the existence of bias proves that such a result must be false and thus any evidence to the contrary must also be false (even if it can easily be confirmed by a third party). Of course, whether or not bias exists has no relevance on the veracity of a claim. That's like saying a judge declares everyone guilty, thus everyone that went through them MUST be innocent even if they were caught on camera doing what they were accused of. Or a reverse example of this. Confirmation bias always disproves the claim that the dice are fair, even if testing shows that the dice are fair.

This is a rather annoying one I've encounted with a certain video game. I even see this with people who had no idea the game even existed claiming that the dice rolls in it must be fair because of negativity bias, even if hard evidence proves otherwise. Fun times.

Comment: [Genetic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_fallacy) - "a claim is ignored or given credibility based on its source rather than the claim itself".